# Mobile Push notifications and realtime chat Using parse or pubnub in ionic app

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ionic-framework, pubnub

I am planning to use ionic to to create a hybrid chat app. Which one should i use to implement push notification and realtime chat. Either parse or pubnub or both. can i just use pubnub to achieve both functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Ionic has it´s own [push notification service](https://apps.ionic.io/landing/push) in alpha state. You should give it a try. Seems pretty awesome and easy to implement.

Personally I have built a chat app with [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) and it works out of the box. There is also a full [tutorial](https://github.com/firebase/firechat) how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Parse is a great choice for push, but you can send push notifications using PubNub JavaScript APIs too.

I actually write a few tutorials on hybrid mobile chat apps (using Cordova), also tuts for push notifications with GCM and APNs:

http://www.pubnub.com/blog/converting-your-javascript-app-to-an-ios-app-w-phonegap/

http://www.pubnub.com/blog/sending-ios-push-notifications-via-apns-javascript-using-apns-phonegap/

I wrote a tut for for Android with GCM too, if you want to check out :-)